# Python code to count integers based on length and starting digit

Tags: python, count, integer

I have a list of numbers of varying lengths stored in a file, like this...

```
98
132145
132324848
4435012341
1254545221
2314565447
```

I need a function that looks through the list and counts every number that is 10 digits in length and begins with the number 1. I have stored the list in both a .txt and a .csv with no luck. I think a big part of the problem is that the numbers are integers, not strings.

```
`import regex

with open(r"C:\Desktop\file.csv") as file:
    data = file.read()
    x = regex.findall('\d+', data)

def filterNumberOne(n):
    if(len(n)==10:
    
    for i in n:
        if(i.startswith(1)):        
           return True
        else:
           return False

one = list(filter(filterNumberOne, x))  
print(len(one))`
```

Comment: what is `import regex` ? thats not right to start with ... also it is a string that contains characters that are digits so regex will work fine ... its not actually integers even though it might look like that

Comment: Using Python re module for regex, why not make the pattern start with 1 and be 10 digits i.e. `re.findall(r'\b1\d{9}\b', data)`

Comment: @JoranBeasley `import regex` is a statement than imports the `regex` module.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply do like this :

```py
# Get your file content as a string.
with open(r"C:\Desktop\file.csv") as f:
  s = " ".join([l.rstrip("\n").strip() for l in f])

# Look for the 10 digits number starting with a one.
nb = [n for n in s.split(' ') if len(n)==10 and n[0]=='1']
```

In your case, the output will be:

```
['1254545221']
```

Answer (score -1):

So I ended up using the following, seems to work great..

```
def filterNumberOne(n):
    if (len(n)==10:
        if str(n)[0] == '1':
              return True
        else:
              return False
one = list(filter(filterNumberOne, x ))
print(len(one))
```